# Converting a function to not use Numpy (only Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I use the following line in my Jupyter notebook:

```
testdf =df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
```

Which fixes issues with NAN and INF values in my dataset.

Annoyingly, it requires numpy which turns the data into an array (which I want kept as a dataframe).

Is there an equivalent command (or set of commands) that doesn't convert the dataframe into an array?

Comment: `df.notna().any(1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it later says "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" When I tried running a MinMaxScalar, any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

**DataFrame Creation:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, np.inf], b=[np.nan, 3, np.inf]))
df
```

**Output:**

```
    a   b
0   1.0 NaN
1   2.0 3.0
2   inf inf
```

**Filtering:**

```
df = df[np.prod(~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]), axis=1).values.astype(np.bool)]
df
```

**Output:**

```
    a   b
1   2.0 3.0
```